# Compiler doesn't inline anything?

Tags: c++, optimization

I've rolled my own *SIMD*-accelerated math library. It's gotten pretty complete, so naturally I went to conduct speed tests and optimize it.

Btw this isn't premature optimization, the lib is actually complete in functionality, I really need it to be fast now.

So anyway, I'm testing some vector dot product methods against the ones in Microsoft's DirectXMath. The difference between my vectors and the ones in DirectXMath is, that in DirectXMath XMVECTOR is just a naked __m128, while mine is a __m128 inside a vector_simd class that is 16 byte aligned and with an aligned allocator.

Now one would assume that with all possible optimizations enabled in release mode they would compile to the same thing. I mean `int a;` and `int arr[1];` compile to the same thing in release mode, just like my array template class has the same performance as a raw array and so on... but to my surprise my class's methods came up *2 times* slower. I even tried just pasting the SSE code from DirectXMath into my class's method, it still came out slower. So the only thing left was the difference that one is a class and the other is raw.

It seemed for a while that the overhead of accessing it as a class member and/or the extra overhead from the constructor (which is empty...). However I put all the definitions of my vector class methods in it's header and still it came up 2x slower than DirectXMath.

Maybe the overhead comes from the __m128 being a class member?

I don't understand why the compiler can't optimize that away, it's like having a struct with a single integer in it?Has anyone else had such issues?

**EDIT:** OK, so it seems that my vector_simd class is 32 bytes, while __m128 is only 16 bytes, which is strange. When I removed the 16-byte alignment from my class it also became 16 bytes large. But this makes no sense, aligning a 16-byte class to 16 bytes should make it remain 16 bytes....

Comment: I'm trying to read this, and its a bit wall-of-texty. Even looking at the text you wrote, it is difficult to see structure in the question to make it more easy to digest.  The unconventional use of italics and bold for various code things is very distracting.  Do you think you could [edit] the question to make it easier to read?  I would suggest looking at the [markdown help](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to get an idea of what can be done.

Comment: @MichaelT is it readible now?Basically I think the problem stems from the fact that when I align a 16-byte struct it becomes 32 bytes and the code becomes 2x slower, but I don't know why it does that.If I don't align struct containing __128 members, release mode crashes.But if I align them, they double in size

Comment: Why is your code slow? No-one can answer that definitively. It could be anything from false-sharing to a flawed timing program.

Comment: Which compiler you use?

Answer (score 1):

Working out why code is slower can be exceptionally difficult, but for a gross difference like a doubling of execution time, you can get a good idea of at least where to *start* looking by using a profiler. You need to particularly be aware of anywhere where data is copied around, especially inside a loop; that can easily get expensive. (I'd suggest a tool like cachegrind, but I don't know if it is available for your platform.)

Alignment problems are actually easier to detect and fix. In particular, if you have a structure like this:

```
struct {
   eightByteQuantity a;
   eightByteQuantity b;
};
```

Setting its alignment to 16 bytes easily force the alignment of *each of the members* to be on a 16-byte boundary, doubling the effective size. Be aware that the size of things like vtable pointers must also be paid for.